# How to change the content of two tabs container by using one tab using bootstrap 4.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create two tabs containers one of them are used to describe the content of a set of files and the second are used as a list of download links for the described files.

Now what I did is try to control the two containers using one tab only, I saw a solution used `data-target`  with two ID's like

```
data-target="#TabA1, #TabB1"
```

But it seems this option is not working with bootstrap 4.x, so is there any solution or workaround to solve this issue.

Anyway here is my code, if anyone can help me in this.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="card text-center ">
            <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#TabA1" data-target="#A1, #B1" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="true">A1/B1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#TabA2" data-target="#A2, #B2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false">A2/B2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#TabA3" data-target="#A3, #B3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false">A3/B3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#TabA4" data-target="#A4, #B4" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-selected="false">A4/B4</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body" style="text-align: left; overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 600px;">
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent_A">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="TabA1" role="tabpanel">
                        A1
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="TabA2" role="tabpanel">
                        A2
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="TabA3" role="tabpanel">
                        A3
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="TabA4" role="tabpanel">
                        A4
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <h5 class="card-header">Files</h5>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"></h5>

                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent_B">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="TabB1" role="tabpanel">
                        B1
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="TabB2" role="tabpanel">
                        B2
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="TabB3" role="tabpanel">
                        B3
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="TabB4" role="tabpanel">
                        B4
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the mentioned HTML code only I can see changes happened to the first tabs container. But I expected to see the changes happened in both of the containers A and B.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: check this sample [link](https://www.bootply.com/yZ7wFkfiMj)

Comment: any idea, please?

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using exactly?

Comment: bootstrap version 4.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in bootstrap 4.X this has been removed and there have been a github issue to discuss it, it was supposed to be an idea for 4.1 but the idea has been removed in 4.2, thus it's not possible to do so in native bootstrap and you'd need to use JS.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19964